# VueI18n: Translate javascript variable dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

I'm trying to display a notification based on a value returned by the server. 
I don't know how to retrieve the translation value dynamically using the value of the key just received.

For example, the value of `error.response.data.errorDetailsCode` is "invalid_credentials", and the translation is "Invalid credentials provided"

```
import i18n from './i18n';

$.notify({message: i18n.t("error.response.data.errorDetailsCode")}, options);
```

I get this warning on the console:

```
vue-i18n.esm.js?a925:14 [vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath 'invalid_credentials'. Use the value of keypath as default.
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the way:

```
$.notify(message: i18n.t(`${error.response.data.errorDetailsCode}`)}, options);
```